# Sitecore Editor not able to change language on an item

Tags: security, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a Sitecore 8 instance running. I created an editor role and assigned it to some users. In the Access Viewer and Security Editor I enabled the Language Read and Write on the items under System/Languages for the editor role and sitecore/everyone.

However, on an item in the content editor, the user still cannot change the language version of a content item. The dropdown on the right side when an item is clicked. It's there, but it's not functional.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I just realized that the same problems happens to the sitecore/admin user. Now I'm confused.

EDIT 2: It's a multisite and I just found out, that the drop down works when I log in using one of the other hostnames. Strange.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot change"? Does it mean that user doesn't see the dropdown? doesn't see other languages in the dropdown? Or when user changes the language, the warning message about language access is displayed?

Comment: I mean the dropdown on the right side when an item is clicked. It's there, but it's not functional. I'll add this to the 1st post.

Comment: Any javascript errors? Can you try to serialize this item and see what language versions it has?

Comment: Added another Edit to the first post.

Comment: Any exception in the log? Have you tried to use Firebug or Chrome Inspector to check if proper request is sent to the server and what is in its response?